# Populate select box from object if doesn't exist in second object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Sorry for the lame title.

I have 1 object of markers i build like this, with the name as the key

```
markers[name] = {};
markers[name].id = id;
markers[name].lat = lati;
markers[name].lng = longi;
markers[name].state = state;
markers[name].position = posi;
markers[name].selected = false;
```

then i have an array of Objects called `fencesCookie` which may or may not be empty.

When its not empty it looks like this.

```
    [
    Object
    contact: "Vince Test"
    lat: 40.758577
    lng: -73.984464
    radius: 100
    __proto__: Object
    , 
    Object
    contact: "Vince WF"
    lat: 35.86166
    lng: 104.19539699999996
    radius: 300
    __proto__: Object
    ]
```

At the moment i populate a select box for each marker object key, like this

```
for (var key in markers) { // loop through markers and append the selectbox
    appendContactList(key);
}
```

**I want to edit it so that if the key (marker name) matches one of the fencesCookie.contact entries, it does not add it to the select box.**

Cheers

Comment: what is the code of your appendContactList() function?

Comment: On what value should it match??. Should the name key match with the contact in the object

Comment: var key in markers should match fencesCookie.contact

Comment: @SvenBieder $("<option/>").attr("value", key).text(key).appendTo("#contact");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
for (var key in markers) { // loop through markers and append the selectbox
    var test = true;
    for(var i=0, len=fencesCookie.length;i<len;i++){
        if(key==fencesCookie[i].contact) {
            test=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(test) appendContactList(key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I correctly understood your object/array structure, but I guess this code will give you an idea:

```
markerloop: for (var key in markers) {
    for (var i=0; i<fencesCookie.length; i++)
        if (fencesCookie[i].id == key)
// or is it fencesCookie[i].contact == markers[key].id ?
             continue markerloop;
    // else the key was not found
    appendContactList(key); // append the selectbox
}
```